# Для чего нужны фигурные скобки при обявлении переменной?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Недавно начал учить Node.js хотелось бы узнать значения данных скобок при объявлении переменной.

```
const {Router} = require('express');
const router = Router();
```

Comment: Деструктуризация. https://learn.javascript.ru/destructuring-assignment

Comment: В фигурных скобках создаётся объект, а не массив, или, скажем, строка.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Это называется [деструктуризация](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). По ссылке сначала про массивы, ниже про объекты. Проще говоря, есть у тебя вот такой объект

`const o = { a: 1, b: 2, c:3 }`

Предположим, тебе нужно оттуда взять значение `a`. Для этого обычно ты бы делал что-то вроде такого
`let aProp = o.a;`

Но это надо придумать имя этой переменной (а мы же знаем, как это трудно порой :)), объявить её и всё такое. Вместо этого был придуман синтаксис деструктуризации. Вот мы знает, что у объекта `o` есть поле `a`, и не хотим мы это поле как-то подругому назвать, а хотим работать с ним, как с `a`.

`const { a } = o;` - означает создай переменную с именем поля `a` из объекта `o`, потому что мы знаем что там такое поле есть. Если нет, вернёт `undefined`. В общем, более красивый и лаконичный синтаксис.

```js
let o = {a:1, b:2, c:3};
let aProp = o.a;
console.log(aProp);
let {a} = o;
console.log(a, aProp === a); // то же самое поле
let {f} = o;
console.log(f);
```

В твоём случае с экспресом мы знаем, что либа нам даёт поле `Router`, мы бы могли сделать что-то вроде

`const express = require('express');`

`const Router = express.Router();`

Но могли бы и так, как у тебя в примере. Меньше писанины, красиво, лаконично.

Answer (score 0):

`require('express');` вернет объект, в котором довольно много полей. Часто нужны только несколько из них. В Вашем случае это только `Router`

Подробнее про деструктуризацию с примерами можно почитать [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/destructuring)